GCalendar: Search for all series dates
How can I use GScript to search for all my series appointments and control the output so that only the appointment for which the series appointment has been set is displayed?
I have already created a script, but all appointments are always displayed, but only the “setting appointment” should be displayed.
Where am I making a mistake - or who can show me an example of where I'm stuck?
Thanks
function getRecurringEvents() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var now = new Date();
  var oneYearFromNow = new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1, now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

  var events = calendar.getEvents(now, oneYearFromNow);
  var recurringEvents = events.filter(function(event) {
    return event.isRecurringEvent();
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < recurringEvents.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(recurringEvents[i].getTitle());
  } 
}


try:
function getRecurringEvents() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var now = new Date();
  var oneYearFromNow = new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1, now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

  var events = calendar.getEvents(now, oneYearFromNow);
  var masterEvents = new Set();

  // Filter recurring events and collect the series (master) events
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    if (event.isRecurringEvent()) {
      // Get the series (master) event
      var series = event.getSeries();
      if (!masterEvents.has(series.getId())) {
        masterEvents.add(series.getId());
        Logger.log(series.getTitle());
      }
    }
  }
}

update:
function getRecurringEvents() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var now = new Date();
  var oneYearFromNow = new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1, now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

  var events = calendar.getEvents(now, oneYearFromNow);
  var masterEvents = new Set();

  // Filter recurring events and collect the series (master) events
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    if (event.isRecurringEvent()) {
      // Get the series (master) event
      var series = event.getEventSeries();
      if (!masterEvents.has(series.getId())) {
        masterEvents.add(series.getId());
        Logger.log(series.getTitle());
      }
    }
  }
}


Mega super - many thanks
You must replace:
var series = event.getSeries();
to:
var series = event.getEventSeries();
I still have a lot to learn
